# Find and replace numeric values preceding a substring

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe which looks as following:

```
df['col1'].values

array(['cat 113kd29',     'do56goat24kdasd',     'pig145kd'])
```

I need to create a new column `df['vals']` with following values:

```
cat 29
do56goatasd
pig
```

i.e. first I need to look for substring `kd` and then find the numeric value preceding it. I am not sure how to go about this.

There can be multiple numeric values in each string so I need to find only ones before `kd`. Please note the string 'cat 113kd29'. Also look at 'do56goat24kdasd'

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
df['col1'].str.replace(r'(\d+)kd', '')
```

Comment: `but it didn't work` ... your current call to `str.replace` should in fact work.  What is the output you get, if not what is expected above?

Comment: It just doesn't do anything and produces the original column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to match digits preceding`kd` and `kd` and replace it with nothing

```
df["col1"]=df.col1.str.replace('\d+kd\Z','', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `str.replace` is correct, but you need to assign it to the original Pandas column on the left hand side of an assignment:

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r'\d+kd', '')
```

Note that `str.replace` does a global replacement by default, so there is no need to use any sort of flag.